# Property set not getting used when changing a property of the property

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I have a super simple class Point:

```
class Point
{
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public double X;
    public double Y;
}
```

I use Point in a Box class:

```
internal class Box
{
    private Point _upperLHCorner = new Point();
    private Point _lowerRHCorner = new Point();

    internal Box() { }

    public Point UpperLHCorner
    {
        get
        {
            return _upperLHCorner;
        }

        set
        {
            this._upperLHCorner = value;
            _lowerRHCorner.X = _upperLHCorner.X + _width;
            _lowerRHCorner.Y = _upperLHCorner.Y + _height;
        }
    }

    public Point LowerRHCorner
    {
        get
        {
            return _lowerRHCorner;
        }
    }
}
```

When I set UpperLHCorner.X in my code the setter for UpperLHCorner is not getting called. Instead the getter is called. I need to change the LowerRHCorner backing variable x and y when appropriate. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If you set `UpperLHCorner.X`, then you wouldn't be calling a setter for `UpperLHCorner`. You're not changing the point, only one of it's fields (and you might consider making `X` and `Y` properties instead of fields). Also, you should show the definition of `_width` and `_height`, to make a compilable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the setter of `UpperLHCorner` to modify the properties of `_lowerRHCorner`. The only time setter is called is if you assign a new value to `UpperLHCorner` itself. To achieve what you need to do, you'll have to use a method like `SetUpperLHCorner` with `X` and `Y` parameter. In that method, you can adjust the `_lowerRHCorner` properties.

Of course, if you really want to, you can add event handlers on the `X` and `Y` properties of Point. But that would be... blech.